# Order-dependant Bit Fields

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

How would one go about storing positional information in bit fields (the order in which the fields are OR'd or otherwise)?

Background: It popped into my head last night while writing a part of my game engine. Let's say that we are trying to describe a colour, and as part of that we have the colours that are present in the descriptor (and their order). For example we have the following colour orders on most graphics cards today:

```
RGBA
BGRA
```

The following flags can be used to describe colours that are supported:

```
None = 0x0
A = 0x1
R = 0x2
G = 0x4
B = 0x8
```

However, by using those fields `A | R | G | B` is the same thing as `B | G | R | A`. How would you design the flags and/or operations that can be used to add positional dependence? Bonus marks for adding exclusivity (you can't have `R` and `G` in position 1, for example) and for utility (some clever way that it could be used, possibly in this case scenario).

Comment: I am not considering actually doing this, I just thought it was interesting. Please no remarks about 'premature optimization'.

Comment: If you want to encode the *order*, the most natural thing IMHO is to enumerate the permutation, and use that number. The most natural enumeration would be to be a mixed-radix thing (maybe combined with a Yates-shuffle)

Comment: @wildplasser so by that I assume you mean `(A * 2^0) XOR (R * 3^1) XOR (G * 4^2) XOR (B * 5^3)`?

Comment: No. The reason is that `4! < (2<<8)` To encode the posistion of the four channels, you'll need 2 bits per channel. But no two channels can share a position; some bitpatterns are forbidden / impossible. There are only 24 permutations, and you use 8 bits to encode them. As a hybrid-form you could express the permutation in mixed radix, and use no more bits than needed: to store {4,3,2} you could use 2+2+1 bits, which means 32 codepoints (for which 32-24=8 are still invalid/ wasted) OTOH: to encode 24 possibilities, you'll *always* need 5 bits anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shift the bit field before adding each flag, by the number of bits required for each unique flag. The following flags would be used:

```
None = 0x0
A = 0x1
R = 0x2
G = 0x4
B = 0x8
Shift = 0x4
Mask = 0xF (A | R | G | B)
```

On a little-endian system you would shift it left by `Shift` (`<<`) before each `OR`. The shift left on `None` can be eliminated because `0 << x = 0`. Given the original example:

```
A1 = A
A1R2 = (A1 << Shift) | R
A1R2G3 = (A1R1 << Shift) | G
A1R2G3B4 = (A1R1G3 << Shift) | B

B1 = B
B1G2 = (B1 << Shift) | G
B1G2R3 = (B1G2 << Shift) | R
B1G2R3A4 = (B1G2R3 << Shift) | A
```

To extract the position of each you would repeatedly shift it right (little-endian) and `AND` it with `Mask`. Repeating this until the current value reaches `None` would give you the reverse order.

```
let cur = the bit field we want to check
loop until cur = None:
  let val = cur AND Mask
  emit the name of val
  let cur = cur >> Shift
```

This does not offer exclusivity (you can easily do a AAGB) and it doesn't look like it has any utility.